# Kafka Consumer Poll runs indefinitely and doesn't return anything

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, producer-consumer, consumer

I am facing difficulty with KafkaConsumer.poll(duration timeout), wherein it runs indefinitely and never come out of the method. Understand that this could be related to connection and I have seen it a bit inconsistent sometimes. How do I handle this should *poll* stops responding? Given below is the snippet from *KafkaConsumer.poll()*

```
public ConsumerRecords<K, V> poll(final Duration timeout) {
    return poll(time.timer(timeout), true);
}
```

and I am calling the above from here :

```
Duration timeout = Duration.ofSeconds(30);
    while (true) {
        final ConsumerRecords<recordID, topicName> records = consumer.poll(timeout);
        System.out.println("record count is" + records.count());
}
```

I am getting the below error:

> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error
>   deserializing key/value for partition  at offset 2. If
>   needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.

Comment: if it indeed never returns can you get a thread dump and see where your thread is?

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of your consumer properties

Comment: I have added above, the thread dump and error I am getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled upon some useful information while trying to fix the problem I was facing above. I will provide the piece of code which should be able to handle this, but before that it is important to know what causes this.

While producing or consuming message or data to Apache Kafka, we need schema structure to that message or data, in my case Avro schema. If there is a conflict of message being produced to Kafka that conflict with that message schema, it will have an effect on consumption.

Add below code in your consumer topic in the method where it consume records --

do remember to import below packages:

> import org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition;
>   import org.jsoup.SerializationException;

```
try {
        while (true) {
            ConsumerRecords<String, GenericRecord> records = null;
            try {
                records = consumer.poll(10000);
            } catch (SerializationException e) {
                String s = e.getMessage().split("Error deserializing key/value 
for partition ")[1].split(". If needed, please seek past the record to 
continue consumption.")[0];
                String topics = s.split("-")[0];
                int offset = Integer.valueOf(s.split("offset ")[1]);
                int partition = Integer.valueOf(s.split("-")[1].split(" at") . 
   [0]);

                TopicPartition topicPartition = new TopicPartition(topics, 
 partition);
                //log.info("Skipping " + topic + "-" + partition + " offset " 
 + offset);
                consumer.seek(topicPartition, offset + 1);
            }


            for (ConsumerRecord<String, GenericRecord> record : records) {

                System.out.printf("value = %s \n", record.value());


            }

        }


    } finally {
        consumer.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this while setting up a test environment.

Running the following command on the broker printed out the stored records as one would expect:

```sh
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server="localhost:9092" --topic="foo" --from-beginning
```

It turned out that the Kafka server was misconfigured. To connect from an external
IP address `listeners` must have a valid value in `kafka/config/server.properties`, e.g.

```
# The address the socket server listens on. It will get the value returned from
# java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName() if not configured.
#   FORMAT:
#     listeners = listener_name://host_name:port
#   EXAMPLE:
#     listeners = PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092
```